# HTTPMethod in NSURLRequest

Tags: xcode, swift, nsurlrequest, http-method

I'm trying to set the http method as POST but Xcode says it's a get-only property.

I'm doing it this way:

```
 request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
```

Apple Documentation says I have to declare the httpMethod this way:

```
var httpMethod:String? {get}
```

But I don't understand how it's to be to work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default behavior of NSURLRequest is **immutable**. If you want to be able to edit something in the request, you need to use [NSMutableURLRequest](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableURLRequest_Class/). Then you can set the .HTTPMethod as you did.